# How to use relative import to import a function from a script in the parent folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I import a function in a script, where the function is defined in the parent's child folder?

In the following folder structure, I would like to use

```
root_folder/
    utils_folder:
        __init__.py
        helper_functions.py (where Function_A is defined)
    module_A_folder:
        Script_A.py (Function_A will be imported and used here)
```

Script_A.py needs to use Function_A.

The `__init__.py` of `utils_folder`  is defined:

```
from .helper_functions import Function_A
```

When I tried to import Function_A in `Script_A.py` like this:

```
from ..utils import Function_A
```

I received the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How can I make this work? I am with Python 3.9 x64.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from utils_folder.helper_functions import Function_A
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but this threw an error of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils_folder'`.